# Configuring nginx/ngrest on Ubuntu virtual machine for outside access

Tags: nginx, configuration-managment

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 VM running on Windows 7.  The VM is configured for Bridged Adapter from Virtual Box.  It can go online, has the same IP scheme IP with the local network, and can be pinged from the Windows.

The nginx sample site (info.php) can be accessed in the browser using `IP_address`/info.php.

I have an ngrest service created with [this page](https://github.com/loentar/ngrest/wiki/Example-of-ngrest-service-with-using-the-complex-types), and it runs fine inside the VM's browser using `localhost:9098/pets/getPets`.

[image: ngrest page inside VM]
However, that service is inaccessible from Windows.  I use `IP_address:9098/pets/getPets`.  Can someone show me how it can be configured?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to `pistache` (featured [here](https://blog.binaryspaceship.com/2017/cpp-rest-api-frameworks-benchmark/)) after failing to figure out the solution.  Again, the `hello` sample service is not accessible from another computer.  It's apparent that the problem is systemic.  A friend of mine suggests looking into firewall settings.  Finally, these two commands help narrowing down the problem:

```
sudo ufw status
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

After installing the [LEMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04) stack, `ufw` only allows incoming requests on port `80`:

```
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

This is why both services from `pistache` and `ngrest` are not accessible from other computers, while the NginX sample `info.php` site is.  The ports used by these services can be added with:

```
sudo ufw allow 9080
sudo ufw allow 9098
```

The opened ports are shown by running `sudo ufw status` again.  However, the `ngrest` service is still not accessible.  Running `sudo netstat -tulpn` shows:

[image: netstat]

The picture indicates NginX rewired to port `81` while tinkering to figure out the solution.  NginX sample sites and the `hello` services (`pistache`) are bound to the `0.0.0.0` IP address, which is different from that of the `ngrest` service.  Googling around lands me [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ngrest/zhIZEmwM6uc).  Apparently, `ngrest`'s author did not mention how to enable the service to outside computers in his guide.  The specifications are located [here](https://github.com/loentar/ngrest/wiki/ngrest-script).  The `NGREST_SERVER_IP` is used to specify a different IP address.  The service is re-activated using:

```
NGREST_SERVER_IP=0.0.0.0 ngrest
```

Now, the `ngrest` service is accessible from the outside.  This feature apparently comes from [this request](https://github.com/loentar/ngrest/issues/7).  `NGREST_SERVER_PORT` is another neat feature.  Thus, an `ngrest` service could be called this way:

```
NGREST_SERVER_IP=0.0.0.0 NGREST_SERVER_PORT=9090 ngrest
```

Anyways, these are the settings that made it possible:

[image: settings]